# Merge results of array of Observables

Tags: rxjs, observable

I need to fetch IDs from my state as separate `Observable`s, combine all of them into one `Observable` and `subscribe()` to it.
I need that my subscriber will eventually get an array of resolved `Observable` results.

Also I need to keep this subscription open, so if one of my inner `Observable`s changes my subscriber will be notified.

This is my code:

```typescript
getTransactionsByIDs(transactionsIDs){
return Observable.of(transactionIDs
  .map(transactionID => this.getTransactionByID(transactionID)));
}

this.transactionsService.getTransactionsByIDs(transactionsIDs)
.subscribe(transactions=>{
 ....
})
```

The result of the above code in the subscriber function is an array of unresolved stores.

How can I resolve each store and combine all of them together?

I've also tried to use `Observable.from()` on the `transactionsID`s to transform each ID into an `Observable` and then resolve it. It works fine, but then my subscriber getting notified on every ID separately. If there's a way to batch all of the `Observable.from()` results (while keeping subscription open), please let me know.

This is how my `Observable.from()` looks like:

```typescript
getTransactionsByIDs(transactionsIDs){
return transactionIDs
  .mergeMap(transactionID => this.getTransactionByID(transactionID));
}

this.transactionsService.getTransactionsByIDs(Observable.from(transactionsIDs))
.subscribe(transactions=>{
 ....
})
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that what you want is `combineLatest`. It wont emit any value till all inner observables emit at least one value. After that it will emit the latest from all each time there is a new emit from one of the inner observables.

Here is some reading material: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Here is an example:

```js
function getTransactionByID(transactionId) {
  let count = 0;
  return Rx.Observable.of(transactionId)
    .delay(Math.random() * 4000)
    .map(x => `${x}: ${count++} `)
    .repeat();
}

function getTransactionsByIDs(transactionsIDs){
  return Rx.Observable.combineLatest(transactionsIDs.map(transactionID => getTransactionByID(transactionID)));
}

const transactionsIDs = [1,2,3];
getTransactionsByIDs(transactionsIDs)
  .take(10)
  .subscribe(x => { console.log(x); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

The `take(10)` is just the keep the example from going on forever.

Answer (score 10):

It's not entirely clear what behavior you want, but you most likely want either [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html), [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html), or [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html).

#### forkJoin

When all observables complete, emit an array containing the last emitted value from each.

#### zip

Subscribe to all inner observables, waiting for each to emit a value. Once this occurs, all values with the corresponding index will be emitted. This will continue until at least one inner observable completes.

#### combineLatest

When any observable emits a value, emit the latest value from each.

---

Example:

```typescript
getTransactionsByIDs(transactionsIDs) {
  const transactions = transactionIDs.map(transactionID => this.getTransactionByID(transactionID));
  return Observable.forkJoin(...transactions); // change to zip or combineLatest if needed
}


this.transactionsService.getTransactionsByIDs(['1', '2', '3'])
  .subscribe(([first, second, third]) => {
    console.log({ first, second, third });
  });
```

Comment: important notice for combineLatest (from docs): _-- will not emit an initial value until each observable **emits at least one value**_

Comment: Make sure the array you are spreading into any of the 3 operators has <= 6 items.  I am actually searching for a solution that handles up to 15 or so without rolling my own grouping of observables.